# Remove duplicates from ArrayList issue

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicates from ArrayLists with the popular technique:

```
yourList = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(yourList));
```

It works, but since the ArrayList is in an HashMap I got the problem.

```
private void removeDuplicate(HashMap<String, ArrayList<LinkedList<String>>> p)
{
    //cycle for each entry of HashMap
    for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<LinkedList<String>>> entry : p.entrySet())
    {
       ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> partitions = entry.getValue();
       partitions = new ArrayList<LinkedList<String>>(new LinkedHashSet<LinkedList<String>>(partitions));

    }
}
```

The problem is after that, the HashMap is exactly the same like before!
The variable *partitions* has no duplicates anymore, but the entire HashMap is unchanged.
Where is the problem?

Comment: how about you match the `partitions` with the Hashmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only modify `partitions` which is only a local variable, you don't actually modify the value of the map entry, to update the value of a given map entry use [`Map.Entry#setValue(V value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#setValue-V-)

```
for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<LinkedList<String>>> entry : p.entrySet()) {
    ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> partitions = entry.getValue();
    entry.setValue(new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(partitions)));
}
```

**NB:** This will remove `LinkedList` duplicates not `String` duplicates

Answer (score 3):

You're never writing the new list back into the map.

You just assign the original list of lists into `partitions` then assign a new value into it, and then don't use that new value in any way.

`partitions = entry.getValue()` is a reference assignment - it copies the reference to the original list into `partitions` variable. *A new assignment into `partitions` overwrites the reference, not the object it refers to*.